# Why does getFeaturesAtPixel return empty array?

Tags: openlayers

I draw the geojson on the map:

```
 const geoJSONFormat = new GeoJSONOl();
    const source = new VectorSource({
      format: new GeoJSONOl(),
      features: geoJSONFormat.readFeatures(geojsonObject),
      strategy: bboxStrategy,
    });

    const layer = new VectorLayer({
      source,
      style,
      zIndex: 10000,
    });

    this.mapService.map.addLayer(layer);
```

It draws the some points on the map.
When I click on the point it calls the function:

```
  this.map.on('click', (evt) => {
    this.map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel).forEach((feature: Feature) => {
       
    });
  });
```

But why `this.map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel)` return empty array?

Style is:

```
const style = [
  new Style({
    image: new Icon({
      ...pointIcon,
      src: `${baseHref}${pointIcon.src}`,
    }),
  }),
  new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)',
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#000',
      width: 2,
    }),
  }),
  new Style({
    geometry: function (feature) {
      const type = feature.getGeometry().getType();

      if (type === LayerType.polygon) {
        const coordinates = (
          feature.getGeometry() as any
        ).getCoordinates()[0];
        return new MultiPoint(coordinates);
      }
    },
  }),
];
```

If replace icon on image it works, but why with `icon` does not?:

```
const image = new CircleStyle({
  radius: 5,
  fill: null,
  stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 1 }),
});

const icon = new Icon({
  ...pointIcon,
  src: `${baseHref}${pointIcon.src}`,
});
```

Comment: I supppose problem is in icon -> image. when I repalce it one Circle it works. But I can not explain why?

Comment: What is `...pointIcon`?

Comment: Point icon it is `"pointIcon": {
    "anchorXUnits": "fraction",
    "anchorYUnits": "fraction",
    "crossOrigin": "anonymous",
    "anchor": [0.5, 1],
    "scale": 0.3,
    "text": {
      "offsetYText": -20,
      "offsetXText": 0,
      "StrokeWidth": 2,
      "fill": "rgb(0, 65, 126, 23%)",
      "font": "bold",
      "scale": 1
    },
    "color": "rgb(162,144,97)",
    "src": "assets/images/point.svg"
  },`